# What after added shopify store into shipstation

Tags: shopify

Hello I have added shopify store into shipstation by following this video:

```
http://www.shipstation.com/partners/shopify/
```

But now how can I know that it setted up and what is the next procedure ?
In shipstation I find one AIP key generator. What is the use of that key ? should i use in my shopify site ?

> How does shipstation work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Aaron and I work Tech Support at ShipStation. The setup process for our connection to Shopify only involves an authentication sign on with your Shopify credentials. The API key generator you see in ShipStation's UI is **not required** to create a connection between ShipStation and Shopify.

Those API keys are for use to connect directly to ShipStation's API: http://www.shipstation.com/developer-api/#/reference

So if you followed the directions outlined in the video you posted then you have a complete connection between your Shopify account and ShipStation. If you are still having any issues with the setup process or have any other questions please feel free to reach out to us via a support ticket here:

https://help.shipstation.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: aaron, getting same issue 401 in get rates api